# Can I use dictonary method, or is there a better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can I use dictonary method, or is there a better way to do this?

```
if data_msb=='1' or data_lsb=='1' or addr_msb=='1' or addr_lsb=='1':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex1,modify_vector,output_file,line)
if data_msb=='2' or data_lsb=='2' or addr_msb=='2' or addr_lsb=='2':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex2,modify_vector,output_file,line)   
if data_msb=='3' or data_lsb=='3' or addr_msb=='3' or addr_lsb=='3':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex3,modify_vector,output_file,line)
if data_msb=='4' or data_lsb=='4' or addr_msb=='4' or addr_lsb=='4':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex4,modify_vector,output_file,line)
if data_msb=='5' or data_lsb=='5' or addr_msb=='5' or addr_lsb=='5':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex5,modify_vector,output_file,line)
if data_msb=='6' or data_lsb=='6' or addr_msb=='6' or addr_lsb=='6':
     print_hex_vector(hexF,hex6,modify_vector,output_file,line)
```

Comment: Use indents after conditionals. No one wants to read that mess.

Comment: there's _always_ a better way that code copy/paste 6 times

Answer (score 1):

Why not put all the `hexN` variables in a list and iterate it?

```
for i in range(len(hexes)):
    if str(i+1) in [data_msb, data_lsb, addr_msb, addr_lsb]:
        print_hex_vector(hexF, hex[i], modify_vector, output_file, line)
```

Comment: why not creating a set of integer keys so you save the `str` conversion?

Comment: also `range(len(hexes))` is clumsy: `enumerate(hexes,1)` is more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Like *Dijstra* said:

> "*Two or more, use a `for`*" - Edsger W. Dijstra

This actually is a mantra against copy-pasting and slighly modifying code. From the moment you have to do that, you should start thinking about "*How can I generalize this?*".

What about using:

```
setvals = {data_msb,data_lsb,addr_msb,addr_lsb}
for vl,hx in [('1',hex1),('2',hex2),('3',hex3),('4',hex4),('5',hex5),('6',hex6)]:
    if vl in setvals:
        print_hex_vector(hexF,hx,modify_vector,output_file,line)
```

In case the values **numerical strings** like `'1'`, `'2'`, etc. You can use:

```
setvals = {data_msb,data_lsb,addr_msb,addr_lsb}
for vl,hx in enumerate([hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4,hex5,hex6],1):
    if str(vl) in setvals:
        print_hex_vector(hexF,hx,modify_vector,output_file,line)
```

The `1` in enumerate is used to state that the values start with `'1'`.

Using a `set` will boost performance slightly. Since now lookups will - on average - be done in *O(1)* and thus probably reduce the amount of checks.

Comment: why not creating a set of integer keys then you can use enumerate?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: because the order of the evaluate can matter. `print_hex_vector` probably has side effects. So you want to print 1 before 2.